# Git how to ignore all files have it's name contain a given text string?

Tags: git

I edit conflict after merged, then cancel it (not resolve), git still remains all version of this file, include: BACKUP, BASE, LOCAL, REMOTE.. as showed in image: [image: Image file]

Is possible that I can ignore all files have it's name contain above text patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete these files. They have been added by git because of the conflict and I think they are used to show you the differences between the local file, the one on the server, ... to help you solve the conflict. As long as you keep "string.xml", it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a .gitignore file and recording the filename patterns that you want to ignore.

See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). The page contains a link to examples, showing how to customise the patterns.

That will not resolve your merge issues though. Git might keep complaining as long as the merge issues haven't been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The files that you have highlighted are generated by a merge tool.

If you have recently completed a merge and you have resolved all conflicts with your `strings.xml` file it is now safe to delete those generated files.

You will not need them in the project any longer because they only pertain to that specific merge.